# Issue with modal window size using Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using jQuery 1.8.2 on the site, and when I attempt to use the Colorbox plugin and initiate the modal window for a gallery, the modal window fills the entire height of the page vs the entire height of the viewport.

You can see an example here: http://www.sportscardslist.com/release/2013/panini-prestige-football

If you click on one of the 6 images at the bottom of the first section, the modal window has some issues with size.

Anyone have any ideas what causes this?

Comment: You might want to use an isolated demo, like one on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) rather than a whole site. You question is more meaningful if code was placed here as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is just the `DOCTYPE` of your page. You're using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

which puts the browser in quirks mode. As a result, jquery can't calculate the window height correctly. You should be using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then the window height will be correctly calculated and the gallery will be appropriately sized as a percentage of that height.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Don't worry - I did too. :)

Comment: May I ask how you came across the solution? What is the train of thought? The first thing I did was remove all other unnecessary scripts and elements, and that didn't help. From there, all was a loss.

Comment: At first I assumed the percentages were the problem and was going to suggest setting the height parameter via some javascript based on `$(window).height()`. Only when I tried that, I discovered that `$(window).height()` wasn't returning the correct value. In trying to figure out why, I eventually theorised that the `DOCTYPE` might have been at fault, tried changing it, and found that fixed the problem. Further investigation led me to [a jquery blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/) which confirmed the quirks mode issues.